# VoiceOver not reading UITextField subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, voiceover

I've got a few custom UITableViewCells that I'm making accessible. I'm trying to get VoiceOver to read all the subviews when the cell is tapped. From my understanding, this is something you get for free when using or sublcassing UITableViewCell (Correct me if I'm wrong on that.)

The issue is in a few of my cells. In most of my cells, everything reads correctly. However, when I tap on a cell that contains a UITextField (or subclass of UITextField) it does not read the UITextField. It will read all the other elements (except the UIButton on one cell as well,) but will skip the text fields.

Does anyone know any reasons it would not read the UITextFields? And the one UIButton? Is there something special that needs to be done for those to be read? Or something special to be done to a UITableViewCell subclass that I haven't done?

Sorry for posting no code, I'm not really sure what code would be relevant to post since I don't see anything related to accessibility at all in the code. In the storyboard, it is selected as accessible for all elements I want read, however the UITextFields seem to ignore this setting.

Comment: At any point in your code are you modifying the accessibilityElements which is an array ?

Comment: I never modify, or even touch, the accessibilityElements at any point in the subclass hierarchy for any of my cells -- so I never add the elements which are being read or remove the elements which are not being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create a custom cell class, and override the accessibilityLabel property of that class.  Collecting all subviews accessibility labels.  I'm on a windows machine now, so pardon if this doesn't quite compile, but you should get the idea.

```
@implementation MyCustomCellViewClass

-(NSString*)accessibilityLabel {

    NSMutableString* result = [NSMutableString new];
    for (subview in [view accessibilityElementViews]) {
        [result append:subview.accessibilityLabel];
    }
    return result;
}
```

By including this as a property override, rather than setting accessibility labels at all potential points that it changes, you remove the concern of future devs overriding this behavior.  You also gain automatic handling of dynamic elements within these cells, as the accessibility label will simply stay in sync with the accessibility information of the subviews.  You can then include this class as a parent class of any future subclasses to trivially maintain this behavior.  If any of your devs are dumb enough to remove this sub class from the inheritance tree you have bigger problems to deal with!

Make sure with this approach that your cell has the correct role.  Whatever the active element of the cell is (be it a tab, link, button, etc) should be the role of your super view.  The other elements are just informative.

Comment: So the issue with this is very similar to the suggestion above -- we don't touch any accessibility elements or anything at all, but seemingly some of our views aren't being set to accessible. I'm fairly certain it has something to do with the behavior of a UITextField and accessibility, and I'd really like to fix the root issue of the problem instead of creating a workaround.

Comment: If you have more than one active element in a group of accessibility elements, you have to use an approach like this.  That's just the way the APIs work.  If you provide a Gist or open source example, I'd be happy to dig a little deeper.  But, the question doesn't provide enough detail for me to really put together a minimalist example.

Comment: What is considered an "active element" here? I took a cell that worked and simply changed the type of a `UILabel` to `UITextField` and that caused it to also not get read, when it previously worked as a `UILabel`.

Comment: A UITextField is editable, and therefore can be considered active, even if you're not allowing it to be editable.  You could try enabling the Static Text trait, but I doubt this will work.

Comment: Do you know of any articles where I could read up on active elements and accessibility? This is the first time someone has mentioned "active" elements having an effect on accessibility/voice over.

Comment: It's common sense.  If you're trying to group items in a cell, and more than one of them is active.  If you treat them all as one element, you can only interact with one element.  I write an accessibility blog, I will add this to the list of topics, but no, Native A11y issues/APIs are horribly poorly documented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97006/discussion-between-chriscm-and-bill-l).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your table cell  has 4 elements a label, a button, a text field, a image view. All these elements are in the `contentView` of your tablecell.

To make sure the voice over reads all the 4 elements in your table cell, you need to tell the voice over that your `contentview` contains 4 elements.You can do this by adding all the elements in your `contentView` to the `contentView`'s `accessibilityElements` Array.

```
 contentView.accessibilityElements=@[label,button,textField,imageView];
```

Then the voice over will not skip any of these 4 elements.

Comment: I just tried adding all the elements in the cell to accessibility, this caused it to not recognize a tap on the cell and instead read each element individually when I tapped on it.

Comment: Yes, sorry if that wasn't made clear. When I tap on the cell, it reads out the title label, and the description label, but skips over my dollar textField and help button. I would like it to read all of them at once, but can't figure out why it is skipping over two of the elements. And it seems to consistently skip the text fields -- however I'm not sure if that is the only elements it is or would skip.

Comment: In that case, you can simply make one accessibility label for your cell, and this accessibility labels should contains the accessibility labels of your elements.

Comment: The only reason I'm hesitant to do it this way is because we have a number of custom cells with this issue, so there's something else wrong here that will continue to affect the cells as we re-use them in the app, or subclass the broken part again for another cell -- if another dev on the project forgets to add the big accessibility label and then a few months down the road it's caught and I'm not on the project, it will cause more issues. I'd like to try to find the root issue of why my `UITextField`s aren't being read if I can.

Comment: In what order did you arrange the elements in the cell?

Comment: They're all setup in a nib file, I then edit the TextField to display the correct dollar amount in its `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: try to disable the accessibility for label, descripiton label and all other elemnts except text field, see if voice over reads it in the first attempt. If it doesnt, then you should provide a custom accessible string for each cell.I am suggesting this because, this is the only solution we came up with in our company for our product.

Comment: Disabling all of it causes nothing to be read when the cell is selected. When I select one of the disabled elements it selects the cell as a whole, but reads nothing. I can still individually select the text field and have it read.

Comment: i mean diabling the individual element

Comment: Do you mean disabling each other element individually and trying it then?

Comment: yeah, try to make voice over read only the textfield and skip all other elements.

Comment: So I can get VoiceOver to read the TextField individually, but never to be read as part of the cell. I've tried just about every combination of accessibility enabled or disabled for the other elements, it'll never read the actual text field I want it to read.